# Under what conditions is the identity |a-c| = |a-b| + |b-c| true?

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

As the title suggests, I need to find out under what conditions the identity |a-c| = |a-b| + |b-c| is true.

I really have no clue as to where to start it. I know that I must know under what conditions the two sides of a triangle are equal to the remaining one. However, I really can't figure out when is that true. Would anyone care to enlighten me as to how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hint: $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ for real $x,y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same sign (or at least one of them is $0$).

Comment: Hint: $|a-b|+|b-c|$ is the distance from $a$ to $b$ and then from $b$ to $c\,$ i.e. the distance from $a$ to $c$ going via $b$. The left hand side is just the normal distance from $a$ to $c$.

Comment: It would certainly work for b = c  and a = b by just "looking at it"

Comment: Dear Danimal, Regarding "I know that I must know under what conditions the two sides of a triangle are equal to the remaining one. However, I really can't figure out when is that true", picture a triangle in your head.  Is the sum of the lengths of the two shorter sides equal to, less than, or greater than, the sum of the longer side?  Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think in terms of distances!

Put $a$ and $c$ on a line. Note that $|a-c|$ is the distance between $a$ and $c$.
Now if you put a third point $b$ somewhere between $a$ and $c$, it is clear that $|a-b|+|b-c|=|a-c|$. If you move $b$ so it is no longer between $a$ and $c$, you will see that it is no longer true.

A nice thing with this geometric approach is that it provides a generalisation to higher dimensions. If you consider $a,b,c$ as points in the plane (or in space), the same conclusion holds: $|a-c|=|a-b|+|b-c|$ if and only if $b$ lies on the line segment between $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

if $a<c \implies a<b<c$  and  if $c<a \implies c<b<a$ with those condition that identify is   always true. So for any b in the interval $(a,c)$ or $(c,a)$ the identity $|a-c| = |a-b| + |b-c|$   is true."